# Google Sheets: With Two Data Points, Link to Driving Directions

Tags: google-sheets, distance, directions

With Google Sheets, if I take a four column spreadsheet and label it thusly:

```
    Shipment #  Origin        Destination      Miles
    A00001      New York, NY  Los Angeles, CA  2,790
    A00002      Houston, TX   Seattle, WA      2,343
```

Is there a script or way to add in some Google Maps logic to automatically link the miles column to Google Maps driving directions, as well as automatically fill in column D with the actual driving miles?  E.G., If one were to click on the 2,790, it would open up a new tab with the driving directions for New York, NY to Los Angeles, CA?

I did find the following to automate mile calculations which gets me half way there (on the interwebs):

```
function getDirection(city1, city2, unit) {
var directions = Maps.newDirectionFinder()
  .setOrigin(city1).setDestination(city2)
  .setMode(Maps.DirectionFinder.Mode.DRIVING)
  .getDirections();
var d = directions.routes[0].legs[0].distance.text;

var distance, value = d.split(" ")[0].replace(",", ""), text = d.split(" ") [1];
if(text == unit) {
  distance = value;
} else if(text == "km" && unit == "mi") {
  distance = value / 1.6;
} else {
  distance = value * 1.6;
}
return Math.round(distance);
}
```

Creating the function for column D:

```
=if(b2=0,ʺ ʺ,getDirection(B2, C2, ʺmiʺ))
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Eek getting down-voted for some reason.  Am I unclear with my request?   ><

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out, basically:

=if(B2=0,ʺ ʺ,if(C2=0,ʺ ʺ,HYPERLINK(ʺhttps://www.google.com/maps/dir/ʺ & b2 & ʺ/ʺ & C2,getDirection(b2, c2, ʺmiʺ))))

Just in case anyone else had the same question I did!

Comment: I have tried to replicate your solution but I can´t make it work. I get a perseerror. Does it work for you?